# Table tbody vertical scrollbar flickering on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to make the header row of a table fixed. I accomplished that by adding `overflow-y:scroll` to table tbody. I also added some javascript to adjust the table's children width.

When testing this in Mozilla Firefox I noticed that the vertical scrollbar was flickering when moving the horizontal scrollbar right or left.

Here is the `codepen` for it.
Please open with both Firefox and Chrome(or other browsers, but definitely Firefox).

https://codepen.io/danae-vogiatzi/pen/BOPLow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem happen due to the fact that Firefox handles scroll asynchronously.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects

> Often scrolling effects are implemented by listening for the scroll event and then updating elements on the page in some way (usually the CSS position or transform property.) [...]
>
> These effects work well in browsers where the scrolling is done synchronously on the browser's main thread. However, most browsers now support some sort of asynchronous scrolling in order to provide a consistent 60 frames per second experience to the user. In the asynchronous scrolling model, the visual scroll position is updated in the compositor thread and is visible to the user before the scroll event is updated in the DOM and fired on the main thread. This means that the effects implemented will lag a little bit behind what the user sees the scroll position to be. This can cause the effect to be laggy, janky, or jittery — in short, something we want to avoid.

This means that the children width computation is time independent of the scroll event. You have to come out with a pure CSS solution or adjust children widths independently of the scroll event if you want to support firefox. or just accept it as a minor problem and move on.